# how to proguard android jar

Tags: android, proguard

i know how to  proguard android project,but at present i use android do a jar so that people can use my jar in the android app,but  i want to my jar to proguard .i  used proguard tool, my .pro file is:

```
-libraryjars 'D:\Android\android-sdk\platforms\android-7\android.jar'

-optimizationpasses 5
 -dontusemixedcaseclassnames 
 -dontskipnonpubliclibraryclasses 
  -dontpreverify 
 -verbose
-optimizations !code/simplification/arithmetic,!field/*,!class/merging/* 

-keep public class * extends android.app.Activity　　
-keep public class * extends android.app.Application
-keep public class * extends android.app.Service
-keep public class * extends android.content.BroadcastReceiver
-keep public class * extends android.content.ContentProvider
-keep public class * extends android.app.backup.BackupAgentHelper
-keep public class * extends android.preference.Preference
-keep public class com.android.vending.licensing.ILicensingService
 -keep public abstract interface com.asqw.android.Listener{
 public protected <methods>; 
}

-keepclasseswithmembernames class * { 
 native <methods>;
}
-keepclasseswithmembers class * { 
 public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet);
}
-keepclasseswithmembers class * {
  public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int);
}
-keepclassmembers class * extends android.app.Activity {
 public void *(android.view.View);
}
```

-keepclassmembers enum * {
   public static **[] values();
   public static ** valueOf(java.lang.String);

}
    -keep class * implements android.os.Parcelable {
     public static final android.os.Parcelable$Creator *;
   }
it give me succeed,but when i call the proguarded jar in my app,some class not found.

in my project:it give me :import com.ant.liao.GifView.GifImageType;  canot found. my gifView file is :

```
 public class GifView extends ImageView implements GifAction{


private GifDecoder gifDecoder = null;

private Bitmap currentImage = null;

private boolean isRun = true;

private boolean pause = false;

private DrawThread drawThread = null;

private Context context = null;

private boolean cacheImage = false;

private View backView = null;

private GifImageType animationType = GifImageType.SYNC_DECODER;

public enum GifImageType{

    WAIT_FINISH (0),

    SYNC_DECODER (1),

    COVER (2);

    GifImageType(int i){
        nativeInt = i;
    }
    final int nativeInt;
}


public GifView(Context context) {
    super(context);
    this.context = context;
    //gifDecoder = new GifDecoder(this);
    setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);
}

public GifView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    this(context, attrs,0);

}  

public GifView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    this.context = context;
   // TypedArray a = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs,R.array.);
    //gifDecoder = new GifDecoder(this);
    setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);
}


 private void setGifDecoderImage(byte[] gif){

    if(gifDecoder == null){
        gifDecoder = new GifDecoder(this);
    }
    gifDecoder.setGifImage(gif);
    gifDecoder.start();
}


private void setGifDecoderImage(InputStream is){

    if(gifDecoder == null){
        gifDecoder = new GifDecoder(this);
    }
    gifDecoder.setGifImage(is);
    gifDecoder.start();


}


public void setAsBackground(View v){
    backView = v;
}

protected Parcelable onSaveInstanceState() {
    super.onSaveInstanceState();
    if(gifDecoder != null)
        gifDecoder.free();

    return null;
}
```

//    public void setCahceImage(){
//        if(gifDecoder == null){
//            gifDecoder = new GifDecoder(this);
//        }
//        cacheImage = true;
//        gifDecoder.setCacheImage(true, context);
//    }

```
public void setGifImage(byte[] gif){
    setGifDecoderImage(gif);
}


public void setGifImage(InputStream is){
    setGifDecoderImage(is);
}


public void setGifImage(int resId){
    Resources r = getResources();
    InputStream is = r.openRawResource(resId);
    setGifDecoderImage(is);
}


public void destroy(){
    if(gifDecoder != null)
        gifDecoder.free();
}


public void showCover(){
    if(gifDecoder == null)
        return;
    pause = true;
    currentImage = gifDecoder.getImage();
    invalidate();
}


public void showAnimation(){
    if(pause){
        pause = false;
    }
}


public void setGifImageType(GifImageType type){
    if(gifDecoder == null)
        animationType = type;
}


 public void parseOk(boolean parseStatus,int frameIndex){
    if(parseStatus){
        if(gifDecoder != null){
            switch(animationType){
            case WAIT_FINISH:
                if(frameIndex == -1){
                    if(gifDecoder.getFrameCount() > 1){    
                        DrawThread dt = new DrawThread();
                        dt.start();
                    }else{
                        reDraw();
                    }
                }
                break;
            case COVER:
                if(frameIndex == 1){
                    currentImage = gifDecoder.getImage();
                    reDraw();
                }else if(frameIndex == -1){
                    if(gifDecoder.getFrameCount() > 1){
                        if(drawThread == null){
                            drawThread = new DrawThread();
                            drawThread.start();
                        }
                    }else{
                        reDraw();
                    }
                }
                break;
            case SYNC_DECODER:
                if(frameIndex == 1){
                    currentImage = gifDecoder.getImage();
                    reDraw();
                }else if(frameIndex == -1){
                    reDraw();
                }else{
                    if(drawThread == null){
                        drawThread = new DrawThread();
                        drawThread.start();
                    }
                }
                break;
            }

        }else{
            Log.e("gif","parse error");
        }

    }
}

private void reDraw(){
    if(redrawHandler != null){
        Message msg = redrawHandler.obtainMessage();
        redrawHandler.sendMessage(msg);
    }

}

private void drawImage(){
    setImageBitmap(currentImage);
    invalidate();
}

private Handler redrawHandler = new Handler(){
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        try{
            if(backView != null){
                backView.setBackgroundDrawable(new BitmapDrawable(currentImage));
            }else{
                drawImage();
            }
        }catch(Exception ex){
            Log.e("GifView", ex.toString());
        }
    }
};

  private class DrawThread extends Thread{  
    public void run(){
        if(gifDecoder == null){
            return;
        }
        while(isRun){
            if(gifDecoder.getFrameCount() == 1){

                GifFrame f = gifDecoder.next();
                currentImage = f.image;
                gifDecoder.free();
                reDraw();

                break;
            }
            if (pause == false) {
                GifFrame frame = gifDecoder.next();

                if (frame == null) {
                    SystemClock.sleep(50);
                    continue;
                }
                if (frame.image != null)
                    currentImage = frame.image;
                else if (frame.imageName != null) {
                    currentImage = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(frame.imageName);
                }
                long sp = frame.delay;
                if (redrawHandler != null) {
                    reDraw();
                    SystemClock.sleep(sp);
                } else {
                    break;
                }
            } else {
                SystemClock.sleep(50);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}
when i using proguard  tool to  proguard the files,gf2.setGifImage(R.drawable.a2);
gf2.setGifImageType(GifImageType.COVER);gf1.showCover() and so on ,all the public method not called from the jar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add the following to your `proguard.config`. I think it will help preserving the the enum:

```
-keep public enum com.ant.liao.GifView.GifImageType$** {
    **[] $VALUES;
    public *;
}
```

or bypass the class which defines enum:

```
-keep class com.ant.liao.GifView { *; }
```

Comment: i used 2 method it reduce my  mistake, only GifImageType.COVER not found,can  you tell me how to reduce it?

Comment: define your enum class as static: `public static enum GifImageType{ ... }` and see if it helps

Comment: or in case if it still doesn't help then change 2nd option to this `-keep class com.ant.liao.GifView`. (Note: without brackets at end)

Comment: i used -keep class com.ant.liao.GifView also no useful

Comment: then add this `-dontwarn com.ant.liao.GifView`

Comment: i used -keep public class com.ant.liao.GifView 
-dontwarn com.ant.liao.GifView  also no useful

Comment: i modify my post,my public methods not ce called from the jar,the java file i have post

Answer (score 1):

-injars GifView.jar
-outjars G.jar

-libraryjars 'D:\Android\android-sdk\platforms\android-7\android.jar'

-optimizations !code/simplification/arithmetic,!field/*,!class/merging/*
-optimizationpasses 5
-dontusemixedcaseclassnames
-dontpreverify
-verbose

-keep public class * extends android.app.Activity

-keep public class * extends android.app.Application

-keep public class * extends android.app.Service

-keep public class * extends android.content.BroadcastReceiver

-keep public class * extends android.content.ContentProvider

-keep public class * extends android.app.backup.BackupAgentHelper

-keep public class * extends android.preference.Preference

-keep public class com.android.vending.licensing.ILicensingService
 -keep public interface com.ant.liao.GifAction
-keepclassmembers class com.ant.liao.GifView  {
     public void *(*);
     public void set*(***);
     public void show*();

}
-keep class com.ant.liao.GifImageType { *; }

-keep public interface  com.asqw.android.Listener {
    public protected ;
}

-keepclasseswithmembers class * {
    public (android.content.Context,android.util.AttributeSet);
}

-keepclasseswithmembers class * {
    public (android.content.Context,android.util.AttributeSet,int);
}

-keepclassmembers class * extends android.app.Activity {
    public void *(android.view.View);
}

-keep class * extends android.os.Parcelable {
    public static final android.os.Parcelable$Creator *;
}

## Also keep - Enumerations. Keep the special static methods that are required in

## enumeration classes.

-keepclassmembers enum  * {
    public static **[] values();
    public static ** valueOf(java.lang.String);
}

## Keep names - Native method names. Keep all native class/method names.

-keepclasseswithmembers,allowshrinking class * {
    native ;
}
and i  get the eunm out of the gifView java file,and put the eunm GifImageType as a alone java file